# Compiled typescript inside Docker breaks with: "Cannot use import statement outside a module"

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker

Running my dockerized Node server throws the exception:

`ERROR: SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

I'm using typescript , and running the compiled typescript from the build folder with `node dist/index` after compiling the code with `tsc` on my machine works without a problem. The error only occurs when the app is running inside the Docker container.

What could possibly explain that the compiled code runs on my local machine without a problem but fails inside the Docker container even though the Dockerfile runs the same compiled javascript code I do manually?

My local Node version: `15.12.0`

- Using different node versions inside the Dockerfile didn't help
- Adding `"type": "module"` to my package.json  as suggested by many  causes the error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined` when running the compiled js code.

This typescript part breaks as compiled js code inside the Docker container:

```
import {x} from "../x";
```

My tsconfig.json:

```
[...]
"target": "esnext",
"module": "commonjs",
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
"esModuleInterop": true,
[...]
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:15 AS build

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./
COPY src ./src
COPY tsconfig.json ./

RUN npm install 
RUN npm run build

FROM build AS run

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENV NODE_ENV production

COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install --only=production

COPY --from=0 /usr/src/app/dist .

CMD ["node", "dist/index.js"]
USER node
```

My package.json:

```
 "ts-node": "^9.0.0",
 "typescript": "^4.1.3",

 [...],

 "scripts": {
 "build": "tsc"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply copying the dist folder inside the Dockerfile instead of letting the docker container build the code itself seems to work. There must be a reason why Docker doesn't build CommonJS code even though its specified in the tsconfig. Specifying CommonJS as part of the `tsc` command also didn't help.

This worked, even though it's not optimal:

```
FROM node:15 AS build

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./
COPY dist ./dist
COPY ormconfig.json ./ormconfig.json

RUN npm install 

CMD ["node", "dist/index.js"]

USER node
```

### Update:

The issue/bug was related to TypeORM trying to import entities from .ts files from a given path-pattern specified in `ormconfig.json`. A work-around for this is creating an `ormconfig.ts` instead of `ormconfig.json`, and explicitly importing and adding the entities to the Entities-array instead of specifying a path.